# Moving a button (onClick) to a random position on the screen

Tags: android, animation, button

everyone. I'm sort of new to android development and I've ran into a bit of a problem.

As is it's written in the title, I'm trying to create an app in which a button moves to a random location on the screen every time it is clicked. A sort of a "runaway button" thingy.

Here is the XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:context="com.example.a4ld.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the main activity code.

At first the solution seems pretty simple. Just move the random values into the onClick method. That way new coordinates would get generated every time the button is clicked. But whenever I do that the animationListener class cannot reach those values and move the view accordingly so that the clickable area of the button would match its position on the screen.

```
package com.example.a4ld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.Random;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             //get display size.
             DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
             getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
             final int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
             final int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

             //generates random values within display size range.
             //doesn't work as intended. the button still goes out of bounds sometimes.
             Random n = new Random();
             final int height01 = n.nextInt(height - 0) + 0;
             Random m = new Random();
             final int width01 = m.nextInt(width - 0) + 0;

             final Button button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);

             button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    //animates button movement.
                    TranslateAnimation animation01 = new TranslateAnimation(0, width01, 0, height01);
                    animation01.setDuration(500);
                    animation01.setAnimationListener(new animationListener());
                    button01.startAnimation(animation01);
                 }

                 class animationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                      }
                      @Override
                      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    //moves the view(probably) to match the new button position.
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(button01.getWidth(), button01.getHeight());
                            layoutParams.setMargins(width01, height01, 0, 0);
                            button01.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                     }
                 }
            });
        }
    }
```

Pardon me for any mistakes. This is my first time asking for help here.

Every bit of help will be greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use ViewPropertyAnimator. This animates the view to its future position and you don't need to force any layout params on the view after the animation ends. And it's rather simple.

```
myView.animate().x(50f).y(100f);

myView.animate().translateX(pixelInScreen)
```

Note: This pixel is not relative to the view. This pixel is the pixel position in the screen.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. Feels a bit awkward seeing how simple it actually is.

Comment: Already did, but since my reputation is too low the publicly displayed score doesn't change...